# How to get comma separated values in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a table Called `tbdSales`

```
Brand     Cust_ID  Prd_ID

Aftron  44301   T3485
Aftron  44301   T0628
Aftron  44301   T2952
Aftron  44301   T1958
Aftron  44302   T1940
Aftron  44302   T1939
Aftron  44303   T2419
Aftron  44303   T2045
```

In this table I want the `Product_ID` in comma separated with group by the `Brand` & `Cust_ID`

I have produced the query as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      Brand
    , Cust_ID
    , (
        SELECT DISTINCT second_id + ', ' 
        FROM tbdSales t2
        WHERE t2.Brand = t1.Brand AND t2.Cust_ID = t1.Cust_ID
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ) AS prd_ID into SalReport
FROM tbdSales t1 
GROUP BY Brand,Cust_ID
```

The above query is giving results. But, if the records are more (10,000) then it's taking much time like 5 mins.

Please let me know any other way for reducing query completion time.

Comment: Do you have index on Brand and cust_id columns?

Comment: Do you really need the `distinct` in your sub-query? It will be faster if you remove it. The `distinct` in your main query is unnecessary since you are already doing a group by but the query optimizer is smart enough to realize that and has probably already optimized that away. So, remove both `distinct`, the one in the sub-query will affect performance.

Comment: I have checked by removing distinct but no diffrence in the time

Comment: @KerrekSB what sort of aggregate is that?

Comment: @dezso: Sorry, I meant [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), but I'm not sure if it's a MySQL extension or if that's standard SQL. Maybe MSSQL has something equivalent?

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm afraid the answer is no: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454

Answer (score 1):

Try this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d425/16). It uses [recursive query with CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28SQL.105%29.aspx). For faster results you need indexes on Brand, Cust_ID, Prd_ID:

```
with t2 as 
( select t0.*,
  row_number() over (partition by Brand,Cust_id order by Prd_id asc) G_id
  from
 (
  select distinct Brand,Cust_id,Prd_id from tbdSales
 ) t0 

 ),
  t1 as (
    select t.*,
           cast(Prd_id as varchar(max)) as m2
     from t2 t where g_id=1

 union all
 select b.*,
        cast(c.m2+','+b.Prd_id as varchar(max)) as m2
     from t2 b
         inner join t1 c
             on (c.g_id+1 = b.G_id) 
                and (b.Brand=c.Brand)
                and (b.Cust_id=c.Cust_Id)


)
  select brand,cust_id,M2 as Prd_id from 
  (
  select t1.*, 
         row_number() over (partition by Brand,Cust_id order by g_id desc) rn 
             from t1
  ) t3 where rn=1
 order by Brand,Cust_id
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replay. By Using above query i am geting result but still timing is same issue

Comment: You should create indexes to get results faster. For example: 

`CREATE INDEX Idx_tbdSales_Brand ON tbdSales(Brand);
CREATE INDEX Idx_tbdSales_Cust_ID ON tbdSales(Cust_ID);
CREATE INDEX Idx_tbdSales_Prd_ID ON tbdSales(Prd_ID);`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct brand, Cust_ID, Replace( Replace( Replace(
                            (   select t2.Prd_ID
                                from @Sales as t2 
                                where t2.brand = t1.brand and t2.Cust_ID = t1.Cust_ID
                                For XML Raw)
                                 , '"/><row Prd_ID="', ', ')
                                 , '<row Prd_ID="', '')
                                 , '"/>', '') FROM  @Sales t1
```

Hi, try this.

Comment: Hi Thanks for replay. By Using above query i am geting result but still timing is same issue